# How to ignore layout in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Can we ignore the use of layout in CakePHP? Normally, default layout gets worked or we can specify ourself like

```
$this->layout='userdefined';
```

But,now I need no layout to be applied in a page and which means I want that page to be completely blank. It should process only data what we are sending there. Is it possible? If so, what is the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do:

```
$this->layout = false;
```

Comment: It worked. What I needed is an empty page and I got it with this line.